# AT90CAN128 Random Malfunctions

Tags: microcontroller, error, random

I've got the following Situation.

An AT90CAN128 connected to a LCD,multiple Buttons, Sensors,LED's and engines.
Shown on the LCD are the Sensor Values and a Menu you can go through with a rotary encoder. 
Menu just has some strings which are located in flash memory.

The malfunctions can be anything from using a button leading to restart, random restarts or 1 or more characters in the menu are exchanged with other characters. For example it should be shown "Level" but instead it shows "&evel".

It is on all controllers, 10 at the moment, but the malfunctions are varying depending on which controller and they are also varying on how much Program Memory is used.

The AT90CAN128 is running at 16MHz with 3.3V and Brounout Detection enabled at 2.7V. But it is not the Brownout leading to restarts.

What i need now are some hints on what could cause such an behaviour?

Comment: I would guess "noise".  But, you will need to provide more details about the system, such as: the operating environment; how are buttons, sensors, etc. interfaced; power source details; circuit board details or a photo at least; etc.

Comment: Evaluate the history of the product:  Were the problems there from the beginning, did they start with a firmware update (or new feature set)? when the "engines" are running?  New board manufacturer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial answer is that you are using the MCU out of specifications which must be fixed first. It is not designed to run at 16MHz at 3.3V supply voltage. See the datasheet to find maximum frequency versus supply voltage chart.

Answer (score 0):

I know of a coffee-machine which showed the same symptoms, it has a 16x2 character LCD. 1 or 2 wrong symbols, even mixed ones, on each output. Figured it was either a hardware bug or simply too much noise on the I2C signals. (We retired the machine after noticing that the amount of coffee produced per key-press became as inconsistent as the taste.)

I'm guessing your LCD is connected via I2C or SPI, so the next logical step would be to use a logic analyser + voltmeter and check the bus.

1. Measure SNR
2. Check if the 'lexical errors' occur prior, during or after transmission
3. Check MCU documentation; there should be a way to read the 'reset reason' in firmware to see if it was brownout-reset
4. Check voltages; 2.7V as brownout-limit seems very high (most 3V3 MCUs operate at 2.7V)
5. Depending whether the bus is I2C or not, maybe it's sinking too much current; make sure the power supply is adequate and the I2C-line-resistors are tuned for your implementation